# How to allow IAM user to access lambda function in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-policies, aws-roles

I have two AWS accounts. `AccountA` where IAM user `devuser` is created, In another account `AccountB` where lambda is hosted.
In account `AccountA` I have the following permission policy attached to IAM user `devuser`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:AccountB:function:dev-my-lambda"
        }
    ]
}
```

in `AccountB` where Lambda is hosted I have the following trust relationship policy attached to lambda's execution role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/devuser"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

However when I invoke lambda using the access key that is associated with `devuser` I am getting the following error

> User: arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/devuser is not authorized to perform:
> lambda:InvokeFunction on resource:
> arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:AccountB:function:dev-my-lambda because no
> resource-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add permissions to the Resource Policy of the Lambda function to allow the devuser to invoke the function. Currently you seem to have attached permissions to the trust relationship of the IAM role that Lambda uses.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-xaccountinvoke) around this explains this in more detail.

In a nutshell, you'll have to add something like this to the resource based policy of the Lambda Function.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/devuser"
            },
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to use the CLI to create it, the API call should look something like this (I didn't run this myself):

```bash
aws lambda add-permission --function-name <my-function> \
  --statement-id xaccount --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
  --principal <arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/devuser>
```

Comment: is the resource policy addition to the two policies I mentioned above?

Comment: It replaces your change to the second policy (IAM Role Trust Relationship)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I only need policy for IAM user and then add resource based policy for Lambda. I removed the Trust relationship in lambda for `arn:aws:iam::AccountA:user/devuser`